# Eigenvectors of Diagonally Dominant Matrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, random-matrices

Given a diagonally dominant positive semi definite matrix $A \in R^{n\times n}$, with eigen decomposition $A = U\Sigma U^T$, can we say anything about the form of $U$.

For example, to sample uniformly from the space of matrices with eigenvalues as the diagonal elements of $\Sigma$ we sample the first vector of $U$ from the unit hyper sphere $U_1 \sim \text{uniform}(S^{D})$, and the $n^{th}$ vector, $U_n$, from the hypersphere spanned by the subspace orthogonal to $U_{1:n-1}$. Is this also the case for diagonally dominated matrices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case $A = I$ (as diagonally dominant as you can get!),  $U$ can be any orthogonal matrix, so in this case the answer is no.

There might be something you could say if the eigenvalues of $A$ are all distinct.

Comment: Very good point! Thank you